# How to find the objects in virtual memory?

Tags: c#, java, performance, memory, virtual

Is there a way that I can use Java or C# to  print the objects in the virtual memory of a specific process? I would like to see which objects of my C# application are consuming too much memory. So I would like to print the current running objects in the process. If its not possible are there any software that I could use for this purpose? Please advice

Comment: Use profiler with heapdump analysis feature, eg JVisualVM for Java.

Answer (score 0):

you can take snapshot of virtual memory at regular intervals through a script or tool and analyze it virtual memory analyzers like heapdump analyzer for java heapdumps 
you can write a script taking snapshots or use following tools.

1. .Net Memory Validator
2. Windows Performance monitor
3. Dot trace
4. .Net Profiler

and there are many more with some pros and cons.
you can get and analyze vmem snapshots and find out objects in memory at given point of time.